# Visualize the point-line distance formula $\frac{\lvert ax_p+by_p+c\rvert}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Given two lines

\begin{cases}
ax+by+c=0\\
ax+by=0
\end{cases}

and a point $V(x_p, y_p)$, the point-line distance formula is:

$$\frac{\lvert ax_p+by_p+c\rvert}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

I understand that the $ax_p+by_p$ is the inner product of $(a,b)$ and $V$ as a vector from the origin O, and I understand $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is to make $(a,b)$ a unit vector, but how to draw the $$\frac{|c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$ in the following picture? What is this? Is it a vector?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Consider a point $P:=(x_0,y_0)$ on the line $L:ax+by+c=0$. Let $\vec{n}$ be the normal vector to the line $L$. Then we see from the figure that the distance $d$ of the point $Q:=(x_p,y_p)$ from line $L$, is the orthogonal projection of $\vec{PQ}$ on $\vec{n}$, i.e. $$d=|\vec{PQ}|\cos\theta=\frac{|\vec{PQ}||\vec{n}|\cos\theta}{|\vec{n}|}=\frac{\left\langle\vec{PQ},\vec{n}\right\rangle}{|\vec{n}|},$$ where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the inner product. Now $\vec{PQ}=(x_p-x_0,y_p-y_0)$ and $\vec{n}=(a,b)$. So $$\left\langle\vec{PQ},\vec{n}\right\rangle=a(x_p-x_0)+b(y_p-y_0)=ax_p+by_p+c,$$ as $c=-ax_0-by_0$. Also obviously $|\vec{n}|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $c=-ax_{l}-by_{l}$ where $(x_{l},y_{l})$ lies on line $ax+by+c=0$. Inner product again?